# Type cast not working on array

Tags: php, arrays, casting

```
foreach((array)$arr['subarr'] as &$foo)
 ....
```

...doesn't not work. It throws a parse error.

Why?

Comment: Could you provide the parse error?

Comment: Parse error: parse error in ...

Comment: if I remove the reference it works. but i need the reference

Comment: For what exactly the cast is necessary?

Comment: I need to make sure $arr['sub'] is really an array, because sometimes is false or `''`

Comment: Then have `if (is_array($arr['key']))` one line above.

Comment: Then why not just wrap the `foreach` loop in `if (is_array($arr['subarr'])) {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast to array and at the same time use the items as a reference.

What happens to `$foo` it it really isn't an array?

The casting only applies to the loop.

```
$arr['subarr'] = array('one', 'two');

// make sure we have an array
if (!is_array($arr['subarr'])) {
    $arr['subarr'] = array($arr['subarr']);
}

foreach($arr['subarr'] as &$foo) {
    print($foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why?

This might shed some light into it, however I'm not really sure if this is the case. At least it makes some sense:

If you use `&$foo` you want to alias each value of the iteration. But as you cast the array, it does not exists as a value, PHP can't create an alias to it (or at least this does not make sense).

Instead:

```
foreach ((array)$arr['subarr'] as &$foo)
```

do this, which works and might be what you're looking for:

```
$subarray = (array) $arr['subarr'];
foreach ($subarray as &$foo)
```

or

```
$arr['subarr'] = (array) $arr['subarr'];
foreach ($arr['subarr'] as &$foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with:

```
foreach($arr['key'] as $foo){}
```

Or are you aiming for:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $foo)
```

where $arr is the array, $key is the index, and $foo is the value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that `$arr['subarr']` is an array and then skip the block of code if it is not then you could use this -

```
if(is_array($arr['subarr'])) :
    foreach($arr['subarr'] as &$foo) :
        {Your code here}
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: or `endif` without a semi colon?